# Click events on Pie Charts in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I've got a question regard Chart.js.

I've drawn multiple piecharts using the documentation provided. I was wondering if on click of a certain slice of one of the charts, I can make an ajax call depending on the value of that slice?

For example, if this is my `data`

```
var data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
    },
    {
        value: 50,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Green"
    },
    {
        value: 100,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        highlight: "#FFC870",
        label: "Yellow"
    }
],
```

is it possible for me to click on the `Red` labelled slice and call a url of the following form:
`example.com?label=red&value=300`? If yes, how do I go about this?

Comment: Did something like onClick event on the filled area of chartjs line chart to get some information. I posted my answer here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66570715/chart-js-line-chart-with-fill-on-click-with-full-information-of-its-legend-text

Answer (score 104, accepted):

**Update:** As @Soham Shetty comments, `getSegmentsAtEvent(event)` only works for 1.x and for 2.x [`getElementsAtEvent`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementsatevente) should be used.

> **.getElementsAtEvent(e)**
>
> Looks for the element under the event point, then returns all elements
>   at the same data index. This is used internally for 'label' mode
>   highlighting.
>
> Calling `getElementsAtEvent(event)` on your Chart instance passing an
>   argument of an event, or jQuery event, will return the point elements
>   that are at that the same position of that event.
>
> ```
> canvas.onclick = function(evt){
>     var activePoints = myLineChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
>     // => activePoints is an array of points on the canvas that are at the same position as the click event.
> };
> ```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/u1szh96g/208/

---

*Original answer (valid for Chart.js 1.x version):*

You can achieve this using `getSegmentsAtEvent(event)`

> Calling `getSegmentsAtEvent(event)` on your Chart instance passing an
>   argument of an event, or jQuery event, will return the segment
>   elements that are at that the same position of that event.

From: [Prototype Methods](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-prototype-methods)

So you can do:

```
$("#myChart").click( 
    function(evt){
        var activePoints = myNewChart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);           
        /* do something */
    }
);
```

Here is a full working example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Chart.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var data = [
                {
                    value: 300,
                    color:"#F7464A",
                    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                    label: "Red"
                },
                {
                    value: 50,
                    color: "#46BFBD",
                    highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                    label: "Green"
                },
                {
                    value: 100,
                    color: "#FDB45C",
                    highlight: "#FFC870",
                    label: "Yellow"
                }
            ];

            $(document).ready( 
                function () {
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
                    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);

                    $("#myChart").click( 
                        function(evt){
                            var activePoints = myNewChart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);
                            var url = "http://example.com/?label=" + activePoints[0].label + "&value=" + activePoints[0].value;
                            alert(url);
                        }
                    );                  
                }
            );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works for 1.x version. For greater than 2.x, you need to use `getElementsAtEvent` method.

Comment: @SohamShetty, Thanks for your feedback, I've updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thankyou for this answer. I noticed if you click on the chart (not a segment), you get an error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_chart' of undefined at HTMLCanvasElement.canvas.onclick

Comment: @MattSaunders You are right, a check like `if (activePoints[0])` is missing to ensure there is some element. Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated the example.

Comment: That fiddle helps me solve my problem. Can you make it more obvious though by making it on top or something? Thanks

Comment: I am getting this error `getElementsAtEvent is not a function`

Comment: Can anyone help me get pie chart slice click with chartjs `3.8.2`?

Answer (score 69):

Using Chart.JS version **2.1.3**, answers older than this one aren't valid anymore. 
Using getSegmentsAtEvent(event) method will output on console this message:

> getSegmentsAtEvent is not a function

So i think it must be removed. I didn't read any changelog to be honest. To resolve that, just use `getElementsAtEvent(event)` method, as it can be found [on the Docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods).

Below it can be found the script to obtain effectively clicked slice label and value. Note that also retrieving label and value is slightly different.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, config);

document.getElementById("chart-area").onclick = function(evt)
{   
    var activePoints = chart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);

    if(activePoints.length > 0)
    {
      //get the internal index of slice in pie chart
      var clickedElementindex = activePoints[0]["_index"];

      //get specific label by index 
      var label = chart.data.labels[clickedElementindex];

      //get value by index      
      var value = chart.data.datasets[0].data[clickedElementindex];

      /* other stuff that requires slice's label and value */
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have created a donut chart which shows a text value in the center hole.Is it possible to track the click of that text?

Comment: I should also note that if you want to get the dataset index for things like stacked bar charts, etc., you'll have to use `chart.getDatasetAtEvent(evt)` in addition to `chart.getElementsAtEvent(evt)` above to get the info.

Comment: its supporting to chartjs 3.8.2 can suggest please?

Answer (score 49):

Chart.js 2.0 has made this even easier.

You can find it under common chart configuration in the documentation. Should work on more then pie graphs.

```
options:{
    onClick: graphClickEvent
}

function graphClickEvent(event, array){
    if(array[0]){
        foo.bar; 
    }
}
```

It triggers on the entire chart, but if you click on a pie the model of that pie including index which can be used to get the value.

Comment: This is a handy answer as the documentation for chart.js mentions the event but does not currently give an example implementation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html.

Answer (score 27):

Working fine chartJs sector onclick

ChartJS : pie Chart - Add options "onclick"

```
              options: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    'onClick' : function (evt, item) {
                        console.log ('legend onClick', evt);
                        console.log('legd item', item);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working for me. Basically this update on chart.js 3.3.2 version

Answer (score 17):

I was facing the same issues since several days, Today i have found the solution. I have shown the complete file which is ready to execute.

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    },
onClick:function(e){
    var activePoints = myChart.getElementsAtEvent(e);
    var selectedIndex = activePoints[0]._index;
    alert(this.data.datasets[0].data[selectedIndex]);


}
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, your answer worked. Short and precise. Should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

If using a Donught Chart, and you want to prevent user to trigger your event on click inside the empty space around your chart circles, you can use the following alternative :

```
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data);

document.getElementById("myChart").onclick = function(evt){
    var activePoints = myDoughnutChart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);

    /* this is where we check if event has keys which means is not empty space */       
    if(Object.keys(activePoints).length > 0)
    {
        var label = activePoints[0]["label"];
        var value = activePoints[0]["value"];
        var url = "http://example.com/?label=" + label + "&value=" + value
        /* process your url ... */
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using TypeScript, the code is a little funky because there is no type inference, but this works to get the index of the data that has been supplied to the chart:
    // events
    public chartClicked(e:any):void {
        //console.log(e);

```
    try {
        console.log('DS ' + e.active['0']._datasetIndex);
        console.log('ID ' +  e.active['0']._index);
        console.log('Label: ' + this.doughnutChartLabels[e.active['0']._index]);
        console.log('Value: ' + this.doughnutChartData[e.active['0']._index]);


    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error In LoadTopGraph", error);
    }

    try {
        console.log(e[0].active);
    } catch (error) {
        //console.log("Error In LoadTopGraph", error);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 4):

To successfully track click events and on what graph element the user clicked, I did the following in my .js file I set up the following variables:

```
vm.chartOptions = {
    onClick: function(event, array) {
        let element = this.getElementAtEvent(event);
        if (element.length > 0) {
            var series= element[0]._model.datasetLabel;
            var label = element[0]._model.label;
            var value = this.data.datasets[element[0]._datasetIndex].data[element[0]._index];
        }
    }
};
vm.graphSeries = ["Series 1", "Serries 2"];
vm.chartLabels = ["07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00"];
vm.chartData = [ [ 20, 30, 25, 15 ], [ 5, 10, 100, 20 ] ];
```

Then in my .html file I setup the graph as follows:

```
<canvas id="releaseByHourBar" 
    class="chart chart-bar"
    chart-data="vm.graphData"
    chart-labels="vm.graphLabels" 
    chart-series="vm.graphSeries"
    chart-options="vm.chartOptions">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var ctx = document.getElementById('pie-chart').getContext('2d');
 var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                // The type of chart we want to create
                type: 'pie',

            });

             //define click event
  $("#pie-chart").click(
            function (evt) {
                var activePoints = myPieChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
                var labeltag = activePoints[0]._view.label;

                      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that for version **4.x** the accepted answer does not work anymore. You need to use **getElementsAtEventForMode** instead as the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html) explain

```
function clickHandler(evt) {
    const points = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);

    if (points.length) {
        const firstPoint = points[0];
        const label = myChart.data.labels[firstPoint.index];
        const value = myChart.data.datasets[firstPoint.datasetIndex].data[firstPoint.index];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in the options section an onClick function, like this:

```
options : {
    cutoutPercentage: 50, //for donuts pie
    onClick: function(event, chartElements){
        if(chartElements){
            console.log(chartElements[0].label);
        }
    },
},
```

the `chartElements[0]` is the clicked section of your chart, no need to use `getElementsAtEvent` anymore.
It works on Chart v2.9.4

Answer (score 0):

I have an elegant solution to this problem. If you have multiple dataset, identifying which dataset was clicked gets tricky. The _datasetIndex always returns zero.
But this should do the trick. It will get you the label and the dataset label as well.
Please note ** this.getElementAtEvent** is without the s in getElement

```
options: {
   onClick: function (e, items) {
    var firstPoint = this.getElementAtEvent(e)[0];
    if (firstPoint) {
      var label = firstPoint._model.label;
      var val = firstPoint._model.datasetLabel;
      console.log(label+" - "+val);
    }
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, of using **getElementsAtEventForMode** (**Chart.js 4.4.0**) :

```
.. el.onclick = (evt) => {
    let activePoints = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', {intersect: true}, true);
    let firstPointIndex = activePoints[0].index;
    let label = chart.data.datasets[0]['data'][firstPointIndex]['label'];
    /* url call .. */
  };
```

It works fine, hope it helps :)

Comment: The complete code of Doughnut chart with a percentage tooltip **(Chart.js 4.4.0)** here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77230228/6155490).

Answer (score -2):

Within options place your onclick and call the function you need as an example the ajax you need, I'll leave the example so that every click on a point tells you the value and you can use it in your new function.

```
    options: {
        plugins: {
            // Change options for ALL labels of THIS CHART
            datalabels: {
                color: 'white',
                //backgroundColor:'#ffce00',
                align: 'start'
            }
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true,
                    fontColor: "white"
                },gridLines: {
                        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)',
                        display: true
                    }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: "white"
                },gridLines: {                        
                        display: false
                    }
            }]
        },
        legend: {
        display: false

    },
    //onClick: abre     
        onClick:function(e){ 
    var activePoints = myChart.getElementsAtEvent(e); 
    var selectedIndex = activePoints[0]._index; 
    alert(this.data.datasets[0].data[selectedIndex]); 


} 
    }
```