# Using EVENTS on CHART JS

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js

I have created this simple graph with **Chart JS**:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

    var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [{
                data: [12, 15, 9],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(223, 105, 105, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(48, 104, 193, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(94, 234, 197, 0.6)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(223, 105, 105, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(48, 104, 193, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(94, 234, 197, 0.6)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            mode: 'label',
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            animateRotate : true,
            title: {
                display: false,
                text: 'My Chart'
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            onClick: function() {
               alert("hallo");
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

As you can see I have an "onCLick" event, but I don't want it because it applies to a click on the whole graph. What I'm looking for is a way to apply the "events" "onclick" for each of the different data I have on the chart. I have read the Chart.js documentation and found that the "events" function expects an Array[String], but due to my lack of experience, I haven't succeeded to use a different action for each of the data on the chart.

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257268/click-events-on-pie-charts-in-chart-js

Comment: Hallo RC. This link has helped me a lot, thank you very much : )