# how to determine which bar was clicked on a chart js

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I have a line bar chart using chart JS and what I want to do is to determine which bar was clicked on the chart. I got answers when click any where on the chart but I want to identify only when click on bar and identify the index of that bar so I can show specific details for each clicked bar on the table! for example on this image when click on any bar for the year of 2010 it will give me index 0 and for any clicked bar on the year 2011 it gives me 1. But what I want is when click on the second bar of the year 2010 then it should give me index 1
[image]
my html

```
<div id = "myTable" class="container-lg" style="margin-left: 300px;">
   <div class="table-responsive">
       <div class="table-wrapper">

            <table class="table table-bordered">
               <thead>
                   <tr style="background-color: #4B4B4B" >
                      
                       <th style="font-weight: 500; color: white; text-align:center" colspan="2">Feedback from Thamama F</th>
                                            

                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <tr>
                       <td style="text-align:center">John Doe</td>
                       <td style="text-align:center">John Doe</td>
                   </tr> <tr>
                       <td style="text-align:center">John Doe</td>
                       <td style="text-align:center">John Doe</td>
                   </tr> <tr>
                       <td style="text-align:center">John Doe</td>
                       <td style="text-align:center">John Doe</td>
                   </tr> <tr>
                       <td style="text-align:center">John Doe</td>
                       <td style="text-align:center">John Doe</td>
                   </tr> <tr>
                       <td style="text-align:center">John Doe</td>
                       <td style="text-align:center">John Doe</td>
                   </tr> <tr>
                       <td style="text-align:center">John Doe</td>
                       <td style="text-align:center">John Doe</td>
                   </tr> <tr>
                       <td style="text-align:center">John Doe</td>
                       <td style="text-align:center">John Doe</td>
                   </tr>
                    
               </tbody>
           </table>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
   function Show() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myTable");
 if (x.style.display === "none") {
   x.style.display = "block";
 } else {
   x.style.display = "none";
 }
}
</script>
```

my JS

```
'use strict';

window.chartColors = {
    red: 'rgb(68, 114, 196)',
    orange: 'rgb(255, 192, 0)',
    yellow: 'rgb(91, 155, 213)',
    green: 'rgb(237, 125, 49)',
    blue: 'rgb(165, 165, 165)',
    purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
    grey: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'
};

(function(global) {
    var Months = [
        '2010',
        '2011',
        '2012',
        '2013',
        '2014',
        '2015',
        '2016',
        '2017',
        '2018',
        '2019',
        '2020',
        '2021'
    ];

    var COLORS = [
        '#4dc9f6',
        '#f67019',
        '#f53794',
        '#537bc4',
        '#acc236',
        '#166a8f',
        '#00a950',
        '#58595b',
        '#8549ba'
    ];

    var Samples = global.Samples || (global.Samples = {});
    var Color = global.Color;

    Samples.utils = {
        // Adapted from http://indiegamr.com/generate-repeatable-random-numbers-in-js/
        srand: function(seed) {
            this._seed = seed;
        },

        rand: function(min, max) {
            var seed = this._seed;
            min = min === undefined ? 0 : min;
            max = max === undefined ? 1 : max;
            this._seed = (seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280;
            return min + (this._seed / 233280) * (max - min);
        },

        numbers: function(config) {
            var cfg = config || {};
            var min = cfg.min || 0;
            var max = cfg.max || 1;
            var from = cfg.from || [];
            var count = cfg.count || 8;
            var decimals = cfg.decimals || 8;
            var continuity = cfg.continuity || 1;
            var dfactor = Math.pow(10, decimals) || 0;
            var data = [];
            var i, value;

            for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                value = (from[i] || 0) + this.rand(min, max);
                if (this.rand() <= continuity) {
                    data.push(Math.round(dfactor * value) / dfactor);
                } else {
                    data.push(null);
                }
            }

            return data;
        },

        labels: function(config) {
            var cfg = config || {};
            var min = cfg.min || 0;
            var max = cfg.max || 100;
            var count = cfg.count || 8;
            var step = (max - min) / count;
            var decimals = cfg.decimals || 8;
            var dfactor = Math.pow(10, decimals) || 0;
            var prefix = cfg.prefix || '';
            var values = [];
            var i;

            for (i = min; i < max; i += step) {
                values.push(prefix + Math.round(dfactor * i) / dfactor);
            }

            return values;
        },

        months: function(config) {
            var cfg = config || {};
            var count = cfg.count || 12;
            var section = cfg.section;
            var values = [];
            var i, value;

            for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                value = Months[Math.ceil(i) % 12];
                values.push(value.substring(0, section));
            }

            return values;
        },

        color: function(index) {
            return COLORS[index % COLORS.length];
        },

        transparentize: function(color, opacity) {
            var alpha = opacity === undefined ? 0.5 : 1 - opacity;
            return Color(color).alpha(alpha).rgbString();
        }
    };

    // DEPRECATED
    window.randomScalingFactor = function() {
        return Math.round(Samples.utils.rand(500, 2500));
    };

    // INITIALIZATION

    Samples.utils.srand(Date.now());

    // Google Analytics
    /* eslint-disable */
    if (document.location.hostname.match(/^(www\.)?chartjs\.org$/)) {
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-28909194-3', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    }
    /* eslint-enable */

}(this));        
        var chartData = {
            labels: [
        '2010',
        '2011',
        '2012',
        '2013',
        '2014',
        '2015',
        '2016',
        '2017',
        '2018',
        '2019',
        '2020',
        '2021'
    ],
            datasets: [{
                type: 'line',
                label: '',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.grey,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.grey,
                borderWidth: 2,
                fill: false,
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ]
            }, 
              {
                type: 'bar',
                label: '',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ],
                borderColor: 'white',
                borderWidth: 1
            }, {
                type: 'bar',
                label: '',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.orange,
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ]
            }, {
                type: 'bar',
                label: '',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.yellow,
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ],
                borderColor: 'white',
                borderWidth: 1
            }, {
                type: 'bar',
                label: '',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.green,
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ],
                borderColor: 'white',
                borderWidth: 1
            }, {
                type: 'bar',
                label: '',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ],
                borderColor: 'white',
                borderWidth: 1
            }]

        };
        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            window.myMixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartData,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Wet Gas'
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: true
                    },scales: {
            xAxes: [{ barPercentage: 0.5 }]
        }


                }
            });
        };

        document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', 
          function() {
            chartData.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
                    return randomScalingFactor();
                });
            });
            window.myMixedChart.update();
        });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart Js clickable bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852585/chart-js-clickable-bar)

Comment: @Geshode but I just noticed that it works when click any where on the chart! how can I modify it to be clicked on bar and identify the bar index

Comment: As a comment from the accepted answer says, `'array[0]._index'` gives you the index of the clicked bar. With that you can identify which bar was clicked.

Comment: @Geshode 'array[0]._index' that way makes each group of bars as same index. I mean if we have 5 bars for each year then the first year all the bars are index 0 and the next year all bars are index 1. it gives me which year but not which bar. did you get my point sir?

Comment: @Geshode pls look at my edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comments and understanding your problem, I think I found a solution for you.

```
options:{
   onClick: function (event, elements){  
       if (elements.length > 0) {   
           // To get the clicked element
           const clickedElement = this.getElementAtEvent(event);

           // To get the group id of the clicked element
           const groupIndex = clickedElement[0]._index;

           // To get the id of the clicked element with in the group
           const barIndex = clickedElement[0]._datasetIndex;
       }
   }
}
```

This way you can know, what the clicked element is, which group/column it belongs to and which id it has within the group (i.e. which of the five bars were clicked).

Comment: I think your answer is  right but I do not know what’s the problem but there is something wrong cause now the chart is not showing at all to me maybe there is a syntax error in that code or something it does now show me the error but the chart is not showing with this code

Comment: I have known the problem ... clickedElement const gives me a result of [Object object ] it does not have a value! do know why actually ... so  when then write "  const barIndex = clickedElement[0]_datasetIndex" then its not working. but the groupIndex is working good andgives me the number of group correctly.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in that line. I fixed it.

Comment: I do thank you so much!! for your patient and for your time and for everything

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code inside your chart declaration and load your html table data

```
options:{
       onClick: graphClickEvent
}

function graphClickEvent(event, array){
   if(array.length === 0){
     //load table
   }
}
```

Comment: but I just noticed that it works when click any where on the chart! how can I modify it to be clicked on bar and identify the bar index