# Highlight external element on ChartJS hover

Tags: chart.js

I want to be able to generate a chart and when parts of the chart are hovered (i.e. the point on a line graph), I want corresponding  elements to have a class added to it on hover. Presumably by passing an array of  elements to the hovered data point.

Is this possible in ChartJS? If not, can you recommend a chart software that is capable of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved what I wanted with this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26258671/874691.

Here is my prototype: http://srgunltd.co.uk/chart.html