# Vue js how to emit event on chart js on click

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, charts

I use chart js with vue js, and show some data on dashboard. But what i am trying to do now is to make a function when i click on chart to go on the responsibile table on another view, maybe with filter also.
I mean if i have a chart where i show how many user are and how many user `is_suspended` are on user table, when i click on side where i see how many `is_suspended` are to go on users table, maybe to add also filter to show  `is_suspended` only

this is my chart js

```
<template>
    <div class="container card mx-0 my-2 p-2">
        <Doughnut v-if="loaded"
            :chart-options="chartOptions"
            :chart-data="chartData"
            :width="width"
            :height="height"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { Doughnut } from 'vue-chartjs/legacy'
    import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'

    ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

    export default {
        name: 'PieChart',
        components: { Doughnut },

        props: {
            width: {
                type: Number,
                default: 200
            },
            height: {
                type: Number,
                default: 100
            },
        },  
        
        data: () => ({
            chartOptions: {
                responsive: true
            },
            loaded: false,
            chartData: {}
        }),
        async mounted () {
            this.loaded = false
        
            try {
                let response = await fetch('/home/user-statistics-doughnutchart')
                let userdata = await response.json()
                // console.log(userdata)
                this.chartData = userdata
        
                this.loaded = true
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and my controller

```
$users = User::count();
        $active = User::where('is_suspended', 0)->count();
        $suspendedUsers = User::where('is_suspended', 1)->count();

        $post_data = array(
            'labels' => [
                'Accounts '.'('.$users.')',
                'Active '.'('.$active.')',
                'Suspended '.'('.$suspendedUsers.')', 
            ],
            'datasets' => [
                [
                    'backgroundColor' => ['#695CFE', '#191641', '#F2C335'],
                    'data' => [$users, $active, $suspendedUsers]
                ],
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Isn't this working? `<Doughnut @onclick="$emit('event_name', <any_data>)"></Doughnut>`

Comment: What suppose to pass on `<any_data>` And I don't want to click the whole chart, but only the colored statistics that show how many users are suspended for example

Comment: `<any_data>` is a data which can be passed to the component which will listen that event.

Comment: `@onclick="$emit('event_name', chartData)"` i tryed something like this,  but does not work

Comment: Can you share the chartjs documentation link which you are following?

Comment: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide

Comment: If this can help you- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257268/click-events-on-pie-charts-in-chart-js

Comment: @NehaSoni This works. Thank you, but i want to go to resposnibile view with filter also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250197/discussion-between-neha-soni-and-tilamap365).